# Родительская модель и единичная инициализация

Tags: php, mvc

Привет, сообщество. Очередной вопрос. Я понимаю, что многое изложено, но не нахожу ответа для себя. Синглтон не хотелось бы, из за его отрицания и "антиполезности")
Допустим в контроллере есть Х моделей. Наследование как и положено идет от Model. Хочу как попроще делать инициализацию в родителе, чтобы потом не дописывать кучу параметров в потомках.

**UPD:** Изменил так чтобы можно подключится к нескольким серверам БД

```
<?php
class Database
{
    private static $_instance;
    private $current_base;

    public function __construct()
    {
    }
    /**
     * @param string $parameter
     * @return \mysqli
     */
    public function connect($parameter = 'default')
    {
        if (empty(self::$_instance[$parameter])) {
            if (!$this->current_base) {
                $this->setConnect($parameter);
            }
            $database = new \mysqli($this->current_base['server'], $this->current_base['user'], $this->current_base['password'], $this->current_base['database'], $this->current_base['port']);
            if ($database->connect_error) {
                die('Ошибка подключения (' . $database->connect_errno . ') ' . $database->connect_error);
            }
            $database->set_charset("utf8");
            self::$_instance[$parameter] = $database;
        }

        return self::$_instance[$parameter];
   }

    public function setConnect($name)
    {
        // $database_config['default'] = [...]
        // Тут кстати, при обстоятельствах вылетает нотис, типа не видит он массив в db.php
        require_once APPPATH . 'config/db.php';
        if (is_array($database_config[$name])) {
            $this->current_base = $database_config[$name];
        } else {
            $this->current_base = $database_config['default'];
        }
    }
}

// В Model
    public function __construct()
{
    if (!session_id()) {
        session_start();
    }
    $database = new Database();
    $this->db = $database->connect('default');
    // Теперь как бы сменить и/или базу данных(в смысле DATABASE())
    // Как ниже не выходит, в DAtabase $_instance возвращается
    //$database->setConnect('other');
    //$this->db2 = $database->connect('other');
}
```

Comment: https://habrahabr.ru/sandbox/19322/

Answer (score 1):

Может быть так?

```
/**
 * Приложение, Web, Console, etc
 * 
 * @property DB db
 */
class Application {

}

/**
 * Основной класс для доступа к компонентам
 */ 
class Framework {

    public static $app;

    public function __construct($config) {
        self::$app = new Application();

        //Создаем компоненты из конфига
        foreach ($config['components'] as $name => $component) {
            if (class_exists($component['class'], true)) {
                self::$app->$name = new $component['class']($component);
            } else {
                //throw new Exception("class '{$component['class']}' not found");
            }
        }
    }
}

/**
 * Класс конкретного коннекшена к базе
 */ 
class Connection {

    //Пробрасываем в конструктор настройки коннекшена
    public function __construct($config) {
        foreach ($config as $property => $value) {
            $this->$property = $value;
        }
    }

    //Заглушка для примера
    public function select() {
    }
}

//Класс для доступа к базе хранящий в себе коннекшены
class DB {

    /**@var Connection[] $databases */
    private $databases = [];

    //Коннекшены пробрасываем в конструктор из конфига
    public function __construct($config) {
        foreach ($config['connections'] as $name => $params) {
            $this->databases[$name] = new Connection($params);
        }
    }

    //Получить коннекшен по имени
    public function getConnection($connectionName) {
        return $this->databases[$connectionName];
    }
}

//Базовая модель
class Model {

    private $dbComponent;

    public function __construct() {
        //Тут можно усложнить и вынести зависимость. Но оно вам нужно?
        $this->dbComponent = Framework::$app->db;
    }

    //Переключить коннекшен по имени
    public function setConnect($connectionName) {
        return $this->dbComponent->getConnection($connectionName);
    }
}

//Расширяемая модель для примера
class NewModel extends Model {

}

//Пример инициализации приложения из конфига
new Framework([
    'components' => [
        'db' => [
            'class' => '\DB',
            'connections' => [
                'default' => [
                    'class' => '\Mysql',
                    'hostname' => 'localhost',
                    'username' => 'root',
                    'password' => '',
                ],
                'mongo' => [
                    'class' => '\Mongo',
                    'hostname' => 'localhost',
                    'username' => 'root',
                    'password' => '',
                ],
            ]
        ]
    ]
]);

//Создаём модель, обьект базы данных автоматически создался на этапе инициализации приложения
$newModel = new NewModel();
//Ну и попробуем достучатся до заглушки в коннекшене
$newModel->setConnect('default')->select();
```

Comment: Вот вы так на битрексе писать можете, а на СО просьба как минимум добавлять комментарии к коду, и хотьпару слов о том что это вообще такое.

Comment: Это подойдет для различных БД, но сейчас суть в другом. Без синглтона, по возможности, инициализировать единожды

Comment: @ozornick чем вам singleton то насолил?

Comment: @Naumov - наброска структуры, по заданному вопросу. Код носит лишь ознакомительных характер, а не является конкретной реализацией, так как сюда нужно добавить еще кучу вспомогательной логики, и получится микро приложение. Это весьма обширная тема для поста. Как по мне всё наглядно. Если что-то нужно разжевать отдельно, всегда можно уточнить.

Comment: @ozornick синглтоном здесь является лишь Application. Можно и от этого отойти, но это лишь усложнит приложение и не добавит масштабируемости на этом уровне. Нужно знать лишь меру. Любой паттерн имеет место быть, и синглтон тоже. Главное только использовать его только там где нужно.

> "Любую проблему можно решить введением дополнительного уровня абстракции, кроме проблемы слишком большого количества уровней абстракции"